# Could not boot Windows 8 from grub2 nor rEFInd on UEFI-system with Archlinux

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot, arch-linux, uefi, grub2

I have followed the archlinux beginner's guide thoroughly and was able to install archlinux in UEFI mode and has been able to succesfully boot from it. Everything works fine except that I am unable to boot Windows 8 from GRUB.

I have tried os-prober,as suggested by the Arch Wiki; and when I boot from the menuentry generated by os-prober, it shows:

> error: can't find command 'drivemap'.
>
> error: invalid EFI file path.
>
> Press any key to continue...

The following are the commands shown when i press e to edit the above menu entry:

> setparams 'Windows 8 (loader) (on/dev/sda1)'
>
> insmod part_gpt
>
> insmod ntfs
>
> set root='hd0,gpt1'
>
> if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint =xy ]; then
>
> search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1 5618A11A8A0F9DF
>
> else
>
> search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5618A11A8A0F9DF
>
> fi
>
> drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
>
> chainloader +1

And I have also tried adding entries manually through /etc/grub.d/40_custom

> menuentry "Microsoft Windows 8 x86_64 UEFI-GPT" {

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
insmod search_fs_uuid
insmod chain
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1 5618A11A8A0F9DF
chainloader /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

> }

This is the result:

> error: file '/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found
>
> Press any key to continue...

Please help!! I'd be glad to provide any additional Info needed!! Thanks in advance!! (do help me edit the formatting above, I'm quite confused by the usage of Blockquotes)

Comment: I'm thinking that the real problem is that I don't know the path and name of the EFI bootloader of windows. Could you guys just suggest where it could be and what the name of the bootloader is?

Comment: It's possible that your Windows boot loader has been moved or deleted. Try running the Boot Info Script (http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) as `root` in Linux. This will create a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post a link to it here; it provides a lot of technical details about partitions and boot loaders that will help us answer your question.

Comment: Also, your question title says that rEFInd can't launch Windows, but your text doesn't elaborate. What happens in rEFInd? Do you see a Windows entry at all? If so, what happens when you try to launch it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP notes they have "given up trying a long time ago as (they are) busy with other stuff" and they reinstalled Windows. This problem is irreproducible at this point.

Answer (score 0):

One needs os-prober >= 1.58 (added uefi support) and grub2 with a patch by mjg59@ attached to https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=972355 (or debian one, see http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=698914) so that its helper would slurp what os-prober feeds it now.

Comment: I'm sorry but I've given up trying a long time ago as I am busy with other stuff. Had reinstalled Windows 8... Anyways thanks for the help I might look into it when I have time.

Comment: Well, there are at least four distros that can cope with SecureBoot with no extra fuss (I've finished the fourth one recently and am working on the docs on that).  In case you'll want to have a look, here's my bunch of ever-fresh weekly images based on ALT Linux: http://en.altlinux.org/Regular -- I did test win8 dualboot with those.